# Replacing list in list of list , gives only zeros

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I have a matrice (list of list) say `a` and I want to normalize each "row" such that each element corresponds to the fraction of the corresponding row, i.e `[p/sum(p) for p in row]`.

I have the following code

```py
a_norm[:] = a
for i,row in enumerate(a_norm):
    b = [p/sum(row) for p in row]
    print(b)
    a_norm[i] = b
```

the rows being printed (print(b)) are completely fine but `a_norm` consists of purely zeros for some reason.

EDIT: Adding an example.

`a=np.array([[1,2,3], [20,22,13]])` should give `a_norm=[[0.16,0.33,0.5],[0.36,0.4,0.24]]`

Comment: What's `a_norm`? Also why are you recomputing `sum(row)` over and over?

Comment: a_norm is initialized as a copy of a (`a_norm[:]=a`) and is the normalized/"fractionized" version of `a`.
The sum is recomputed since each row is different

Comment: No it's not. `b = [p/sum(row) for p in row]` don't tell me that `row` varies there.

Comment: I loop over `row`

Comment: So that's what I'm saying, why are you recomputing `sum(row)` each time?

Comment: if you look at the example provided `row` is first `[1,2,3]` then `[20,22,13]` which of course give different results when you sum over them?

Comment: Wow, you really don't see the problem, do you? Just a profile on a real case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
a_norm = [[i / sum(row) for i in row] for row in a]
```

Comment: That works - but the question is more, why the solution I used does not

Comment: I think it's because a is np.array, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hence my comment. The question is imprecise and cannot be answered as stated.

Answer (score 1):

Mistake you did in making list copy.
use `a_norm = a[:]` instead of `a_norm[:] = a`

You can try:

```
a_norm = a[:]
for i, row in enumerate(a_norm):
    b = [p/sum(row) for p in row]
    print(b)
    a_norm[i] = b
print(a_norm)
```

Comment: it does not make a difference - still same issue

Comment: Also using a_norm = a.copy() does not solve the problem

Comment: @CutePoison : I am using Python 3.6 and it is working at my end. Giving the expected output which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: that is odd.. I am running python 3.5.2 using Atom

Comment: I'm running python 3.7.3 and this solution works for me

Comment: @Cyber no, it depends of what are the inputs, but OP doesn't indicate what they are.